# Make windows executable search into a custom directory for dlls

Tags: windows, batch-file, winapi, dll, executable

Say I have a folder `Program` containing `Program.exe` (which I don't have the code for) that searches for DLLs in `C:\Shared\`.

How can I make this `Program.exe` search for DLLs in another folder, e.g. `Program\Shared`?

I'm fine with using a `bat` script or even the `windows.h` API from a C++ program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**: based on new info provided that you don't have access to change the source code of the program in question, and also the fact that the program is already searching for DLLs in a different folder than the one containing the program, then it is very likely the program is using absolute paths (or the APIs mentioned below) to load the DLLs, and thus there is very little you can do to make the program search in yet another folder of your choosing (short of hacking the program/altering the EXE file).

---

[original answer]

If the program **statically links** to the DLLs, the DLLs will be loaded by the OS automatically before any code in the program runs, so the folder will need to be on the OS's [DLL search path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order).

If the program **dynamically loads** the DLLs in code, the DLLs will be loaded after the program's code starts running, so the program can either load the DLLs directly using absolute paths, or else it can use the Win32 [`SetDllDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectoryw) or [`AddDllDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-adddlldirectory) function to add the folder to the OS's search path.

Comment: Is it possible to change the DLL search path of a program that dynamically loades the DLLs without modifying its code? (I don't have access to the executable's code in this case).

Comment: If the program loads the DLLs using absolute paths, there is nothing you can do (without hooking into the program at runtime). But if it loads them using relative paths then you can either change the system's `%PATH%` environment variable, or register the DLLs in the `KnownDlls` Registry key, before running the program.

Comment: @din None of that information is present in the question. That's why I voted to close it. As it stands, this proposed answer doesn't address your issue. It provides a solution under the assumption that you are authoring the program.

Comment: @IInspectable that's a good point. Re-reading the original question, I see now that my answer doesn't apply to it.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes I see now I should've mentioned it in the question, that was an error on my part.